# Django fiter query from relational table

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-views

I'm creating blog, articles are posted only by login.So am having four table such as, User, JSdetails, Blog, comments. This four table are  interrelated with each other. Here I want to display profile picture in comments. I had tried out but not able to displayed. Give some idea for me. I added models, views, templates below...

*models.py*

```
class User(models.Model):
    first_name=models.CharField()
    last_name=models.CharField()
    username=models.CharField()

class JSdetails(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    profilepic=models.ImageField(upload_to='Image')

class Blog(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    btitle=models.CharField()
    bcontent=models.TextField(blank=True)
    bposted=models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)

class BComments(models.Model):
    user=models.ForeignKey(User)
    blog=models.ForeignKey(Blog)
    comments=models.TextField()
    commentpost=models.DateTimeField(auto_now = True)
```

*views.py*

```
def blogArticle(request):
    articleid=1
    article=Blog.objects.filter(id=articleid)
    com=BComments.objects.filter(blog_id=articleid)
    return render_to_response('registration/BlogArticle.html',{'article':article,'com':com},context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

*Templates*

```
/* Here Article will display */    

{% for article in article %}
<h2>{{article.btitle}}</h2>
<p style="text-align:justify;">{{article.bcontent}}</p>
{% endfor %}

/* Here Comments get displayed which is posted by user */

{% for com in com %}
<img style="width:50px;height:50px;" src="Here I need to Display Profile picture" >
<span>{{com.user.username}}</span>
<p style="word-wrap:break-word;">
{{com.comments}}
</p>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: you dont use JSdetails anywhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you set a `ForeignKey` to the user, the user model will have a `jsdetails_set` which is a `RelatedManager`. You could try in your template this:

```
{{ com.user.jsdetails_set.all.0.profilepic.url }}
```

This will try and return the first `jsdetails` instance. Don't know for sure if it fails silently when trying to access the 0 index if it's not set.

Comment: Same Result not yet displayed